# Entity Framework and MSSQL json_value nested array in different row

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am experimenting with the json_value. The goal is to create dynamic model in the database which can contain any type of data using json.

So this is the model:

```
public class DynamicModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; } = "MyTable";
    public Guid? Container { get; set; } = null; //Parent who hold this data for many-one relation

    public string Content { get; set; } = ""; //JSON content

    public bool DeleteOnCascade { get; set; } = false;

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

So for example if the `Content` contains:

```
"{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"cars\":[] }"
```

The problem if I put the cars into the same row, the data will be too big and not efficient for accessing the data.

So I figure it will be better if I separate the nested list of the car into different row:

```
var car = new DynamicModel() {
    Id = ...,
    TableName = "Car",
    Container = //the parent ID of the above example (one - many relation),
    DeleteOnCascade = true, //Gets deleted if the parent gets deleted,
    ...
}
```

So here is how I modify the entity framework to be able to access json_value:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Conventions.Add(new RegisterJsonValueFunctionConvention());
}
```

then

```
public static class JH
{
    // Than define your function
    [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "JSON_VALUE")]
    public static string JsonValue(string expression, string path)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

then

```
public class RegisterJsonValueFunctionConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmModel>
{
    public void Apply(EdmModel item, DbModel model)
    {
        var expressionParameter = FunctionParameter.Create("expression", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In);
        var pathParameter = FunctionParameter.Create("path", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.In);
        var returnValue = FunctionParameter.Create("result", GetStorePrimitiveType(model, PrimitiveTypeKind.String), ParameterMode.ReturnValue);
        CreateAndAddFunction(item, "JSON_VALUE", new[] { expressionParameter, pathParameter }, new[] { returnValue });
    }

    protected EdmFunction CreateAndAddFunction(EdmModel item, string name, IList<FunctionParameter> parameters, IList<FunctionParameter> returnValues)
    {
        var payload = new EdmFunctionPayload { StoreFunctionName = name, Parameters = parameters, ReturnParameters = returnValues, Schema = GetDefaultSchema(item), IsBuiltIn = true };
        var function = EdmFunction.Create(name, GetDefaultNamespace(item), item.DataSpace, payload, null);
        item.AddItem(function);
        return function;
    }

    protected EdmType GetStorePrimitiveType(DbModel model, PrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)
    {
        return model.ProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage.CreateDefaultTypeUsage(PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(typeKind))).EdmType;
    }

    protected string GetDefaultNamespace(EdmModel layerModel)
    {
        return layerModel.GlobalItems.OfType<EdmType>().Select(t => t.NamespaceName).Distinct().Single();
    }

    protected string GetDefaultSchema(EdmModel layerModel)
    {
        return layerModel.Container.EntitySets.Select(s => s.Schema).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Finally this is how I access the value:

```
var x = db.DynamicData
        .Where(m => JH.JsonValue(m.Content, "$.name").Equals("John"))
        .Select(m => JH.JsonValue(m.Content, "$.age"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I wonder if there is a convenient way to access the `cars` with the Linq query?

Right now I have to get the `x` value first, then look for the `cars` which has the `Container` value as the `x.ID`, get the list, then append to the `cars:[]` which really takes time and memory to process it.

So what do you think guys? Is there a convenient way to achieve this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You could conceivably register another DB function to use the JSON_QUERY() function which will can be used to select arrays and objects from within the JSON data.